# $r\angle \theta = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am looking at the Visual Complex Analysis book and the first practice section asks to go through some of the statements about complex numbers and just prove to oneself that they are true. There is one that uses the notation in the title and that says that the angle between the $x$ axis and the complex number vector is $\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$. I know that this is something very simple and yet I cannot show this...

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. The angle between the $x$ axis and the number $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ is $\theta$. You can see this by drawing a triangle.

Comment: No, the complex number is $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and the angle is $\theta$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust if $r=1$. Here, it is $r \cos \theta + i r \sin \theta$

Comment: I reproduced what you call the "complex number vector".

Comment: Oh yes. I see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get something from this picture?

[image]

---

[Added in response to the comments] Note that in the notation $\angle\theta$, $\theta$ is the argument (angle) of $z$, but the whole thing $\angle\theta$ is not. Read page 7 of Needham's book about the property of $\angle\theta$. Note that, for *any* $\theta$ and $\phi$, we have $\angle(\theta+\phi)=\angle\theta+\angle\phi$. But it is not true that $\theta\phi=\theta+\phi$ (if $\angle\theta=\theta$, this would be true). Reading the later chapter of the book, you will find later that $\angle\theta=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: almost. That $x+iy = r \angle \theta$. But in polar coordinates, $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$. But then I have $r \angle \theta = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, which is not correct

Comment: oh no. $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$

Comment: and then I take $r$ outside the brackets

Comment: what I said initially is only true if $r=1$

Comment: You are saying something like $$\theta = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta),$$ which, in general, is not true (it is true only if $\theta = \cos(\theta)$.)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that now. Thanks

Comment: I correct my previous comment. It is true only if $\theta=\cos(\theta)$ **and $\sin(\theta) = 0$**.

Comment: Note carefully that $\angle \theta = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, not the one you gave.

Comment: @Jack I am super confused now. isn't $\angle \theta = \theta$, as per my comment to the other question?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any complex number $z$ can be expressed in 3 equivalent ways:

1. **Algebraic form**
   $$z = a + ib,$$
   for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}.$
2. **Trigonometric form**
   $$z = r(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)),$$

where

$$r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2},$$

and $\theta$ is the **angle between the x axis and the complex number vector**. $\theta$ is called the **argument** of $z$. Please, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) for more details.

3. **Exponential form**

$$z = re^{i\theta},$$

where $r$ and $\theta$ are defined as before.

Comment: yes. But how do I see that the angle is actually $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

Comment: No, it isn't! The angle is $\theta$.

Comment: I bet one euro that you misread the book...

Comment: I bet ten haha. Thanks

Comment: If $\theta$ is angle, then we know that $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, or in general $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, right? Now, how can $$\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) \in \mathbb{R}?$$

Comment: hahah, very good point :) No clue. Apparently it was possible in my mind like 5 minutes ago :)